# SQL - Several rows into one

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

[image: Picture with exampledata]

There are 12 rows in the table in total. Every unique record contains of 4 rows. I want the result on 3 rows/records in total having 4 Fields/columns each.

**Example Input:**
TEST
455
688
987
Texter
567
53
878
Julgranar
765
454
989

**Exampel output/result:**
Column1   Column2  Column3  Column4
TEST      455      688      987
Texter    567      53       878
Julgranar 765      454      989

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: If 4 rows can become one, somewhere must be something wrong

Comment: Most people here want formatted text, not images (or links to images.) Show us sample table data and the expected result. Also show us your current query attempt.

Comment: Which [DBMS product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: What is the logic for deciding that `TEST` should be on the same row as `455` and not `567`?

Comment: TEST, 455, 688 and 987 belong together and should be on the same row. Same goes for Texter, 567, 53 and 878 etc. So there is 3 records on 4 rows each. 12 rows in total then :)

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways depending on some data rules that you have not included, but here is one way using what you gave.

```
 SELECT
    t1.Field1,
    t2.Field2
FROM Table1 t1
    LEFT JOIN Table1 t2 ON t1.FK = t2.FK AND t2.Field1 IS NULL
```

Another way:

```
    SELECT
    t1.Field1,
    (SELECT Field2 FROM Table2 t2 WHERE t2.FK = t1.FK AND Field1 IS NULL) AS Field2
FROM Table1 t1
```